# find the minimum n?

Tags: taylor-expansion

> Let $P_n(x)$ be the $n$-th Taylor polynomial about $x = 0$ for the exponential function $e^x$. Find  the least $n$ such that $\left|e − P_n(1)\right| < 10^{-5}$.

My answer is $9$.  I used $e-P_n(1)=\frac{e^a}{(n+1)!}$ with some $a \in [0,1]$ where I put $n=9$. I just  want to confirm whether it is correct.

If it's not correct, then any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not correct. The correct answer is $n=8$.

Comment: Tell us how you obtained the solution.

Comment: @Martin $e-P_n(1)=\frac{e^a}{(n+1)!}$ for some $a \in [0,1]$.  i put n =9

Comment: thanks@ Crostul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$0<a_n:=e-P_n(1)=e-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$$
and therefore $a_n$ is a strictly decreasing sequence which tend to $0$.
It turns out that 
$$a_8< 2.718282-\frac{109601}{403200}<10^{-5}\quad\mbox{and}\quad a_7> 2.71828-\frac{685}{252}>
0.2 \cdot 10^{-4}$$
where we used the fact that $2.71828< e<2.718282$ (see [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))).

Comment: thanks a lots @Robertz